# Highcharts: detect if tooltip is being shown

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to prevent the automatic update of my chart if a tooltip is being shown. Is there any way of detecting its state? I can't see any [events](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events) that I can use to modify a global `isShown` boolean - and even if there were - I imagine there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `chart.tooltip.isHidden` to see if it is hidden or not (boolean).

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2fus626/2/) demonstration.